# What is the term for when you are forced to respect authorities, but they couldn't care less about you?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term you are forced to respect authorities, but they couldn't care less about you?
For example:

> We have ______ in our house; we are forced to respect elders, but they mistreat us.

Comment: Obedience: the act or practice of obeying; dutiful or submissive compliance.

Comment: @JOSH obedience doesn't mean person to you being obedient to is not respecting you

Comment: Could be anything from pirates to bed bugs; you need to clarify what sort of word you're looking for.

Comment: ***Oppression**?* ***Repression**?* ***Tyranny**?*

Comment: It means that  you have to obey, even though they don't care about you or treat you unfairly.

Comment: @AlanCarmack for some word like `patriarchy`

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes these words are very close but what i want is some word that defines system in which you should do that

Comment: @Jon Snow's papa: There are plenty of words appropriate to *forced to respect authority* (or even *forced to respect **elders** [who are automatically "in authority" in some cultures]*, but I really don't think there would be a dedicated word for the specific case where those in authority ***mistreat*** their underlings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers by mistreat i don't mean to beat up or smth,what i mean is for example smn should be 'authority' is sleeping,but when smn is sleeping authority is not quiet

Comment: Sounds like that authority is in _breach of the social contract_.  But that's decidedly not a single word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think *tyranny* is exactly it.

Comment: @Phil: [**Dictatorship**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dictatorship)  *implies absolute power — one person who takes control — of a political situation, **a family, a classroom or even a camping expedition.*** I can't find any dictionary definition for **tyranny** that explicitly mentions "figuratively" using the word outside the political context like that. Not that I'd take any notice of that point if I were deciding which word to use in my own text, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have [despotism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/despotism) in our house; we are forced to respect elders, but they mistreat us.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, despotism seems to fit the context you describe. If you don't mean to convey outright cruelty, oligarchy might work. We have an [oligarchy](http://www.encyclopedia.com/international/legal-and-political-magazines/oligarchy) in our house...

Comment: Now benign oligarchies; I like it.

Comment: Now -> No.  Fat-fingered that previous comment; sorry.